# DiscoverDevicesInRange() is not returning paired device information which is in range

Tags: c#

```
BluetoothClient client=new BluetoothClient();
foreach (var device in client.DiscoverDevicesInRange())
{
   dev.Add(device);
   list.Add(device);
}
```

Hi,
I am using DiscoverDevicesInRange() from 32feet bluetooth lib to get the nearby bluetooth connections. I am facing an issue where I am unable to get my bluetooth device information from this method when the device is in range. My device is paired with windows. Any idea on how to get paired bluetooth device information which is in range?

Comment: This is not sufficient information. Please describe your scenario and what you are trying to achieve. I would also recommend to use a variable for the return value: `var devices = client.DiscoverDevicesInRange();` and then iterate over that instead. Otherwise, you will call DiscoverDevicesInRange() multiple times.

Comment: I have paired my device with windows. Next time when I try to see if that device is in range or not using DiscoverDevicesInRange() I am not getting my paired device information when the device is in range.